# I want to obtain auto filtering in JTable as in ms excel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I am using `jtable` to display data from ms sql server table.
I am able to sort the data using:

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);    

jtable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

The above sorts the data in ascending and descending order.

Is there any such simple function in java to obtain auto filtering of rows as in ms excel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: auto filtering of rows as in ms excel?, yes is possible, never tried but sorting based on value in concrete column works

Comment: Do you mean `sorter.setRowFilter()`?

Comment: yes setRowFilter(). but not by adding a new jtextfield. I wan't filtering as in ms excel

Comment: `but not by adding a new jtextfield` - why do you think you need a JTextField? Just hardcode the string you want to filter by.

Comment: i want all the distinct data in a column in one combobox and when a user selects one of them, the data related to that selection has to appear (filtering as in ms excel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used [Swing Bits Table Filtering](https://github.com/eugener/oxbow/wiki/Table-Filtering) for this:
[image]

Comment: I have seen this. thanks for your help. can't it be done without using external jars?

Comment: @user1416631 you could take the sources and include them in your project. But why not using an external jar?

Comment: is it a freeware or a priced one?

Comment: I have decided to go with user714965's answer. Thanks much for your help

Comment: @Kai and other : How can I control the size of the pop-up menu? I have a long wrapped strings as data and the autofilter pop-up menu ranges across the monitors!

Answer (score 5):

You may also want to have a look at [Coderazzi's TableFilter](http://coderazzi.net/tablefilter/index.html). It has a permissive MIT license, is available from Central Maven, etc.

Unlike the Swing Bits Table Filtering (referenced in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16277866/1504556) on this page), the Coderazzi TableFilter doesn't mess with the table header. I guess it is a matter of taste.

[image: TableFilter Example]

Comment: I also want to add that Coderazzi's TableFilter was easy to implement and works with native JTables.  I recommend giving it a shot.

Comment: Coderazzi's TableFilter  was indeed pretty easy to implement but it doesn't support multi selection (example in the picture : filter on age 28 and 26) which is a deal breaker for me : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tablefilter-swing/B28WhTudHh0